# Priority of laptop memory slots

Tags: laptop, memory

I am running MX Linux on a 3 year old Dell Inspiron 5590 laptop with 4GB memory which is soldered onto the motherboard. I'm having problems caused by memory errors. Memtest86 reported 70 errors over 4 full passes.

It would be uneconomic to replace the soldered in memory but there is an additional DIMM socket identified as slot 1 and the onboard memory is identified as slot 2.

What I'm wondering is that if slot 1 takes priority over slot 2 then if I add an 8 or 16GB module to the slot then the onboard 4GB module won't get used until all the memory in slot 1 has been filled and I'll be much less likely to hit the faulty addresses. But that's only a guess and I'd welcome any comments as to whether this is a reasonable assumption.

---

**Edit**: I've now installed an 8GB DIMM in the extra slot and the results have been both interesting and somewhat puzzling.

After inserting the new DIMM I ran Dell's diagnostics from the BIOS. This reported that it found and 'resolved' two errors but didn't provide any further details. I assumed these would be existing errors in the onboard 4GB module.

I then ran 4 passes of memtest86 during which it found no errors. This was surprising because when I ran memtest86 a few days ago with only the 4GB soldered onboard memory it had reported 70 errors, some of which would have been duplicates.

I haven't managed to find any way of determining the start address of each memory module but the output of dmesg before and after adding the extra 8GB suggests that the new 8GB DIMM starts before the 4GB onboard memory.

In dmesg the physical RAM map provided by the BIOS reports some areas of memory as being unusable. Before adding the extra DIMM these were:

```
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000042f08000-0x0000000042f09fff] unusable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000052a64000-0x0000000052a64fff] unusable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000052a66000-0x0000000052a67fff] unusable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000079f10000-0x0000000079f10fff] unusable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000079f12000-0x0000000079f13fff] unusable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000104a84000-0x0000000104a87fff] unusable
```

I assume these unusable blocks have been flagged by an earlier run of the BIOS diagnostics and will not be used by my Linux system and that memtest86 also skips them.

After installing the extra 8GB DIMM the unusable blocks have moved to much higher addresses:

```
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000128508000-0x0000000128508fff] unusable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000311cc8000-0x0000000311cc9fff] unusable  
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000311ccc000-0x0000000311cccfff] unusable  
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000311cce000-0x0000000311ccffff] unusable  
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000360621000-0x0000000360621fff] unusable  
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000360626000-0x0000000360627fff] unusable
```

Most of these values suggest that the onboard 4G is now at the high end of memory but if this is so then I would have expected them all to have increased by 8GB, i.e.0x200000000 but the differences are 0xE5600000, 0x2BF264000, 0x2BF266000, 0x297DBE000, 0x2E670F000 and 0x25BBA2000 respectively which are not consistent with an 8GB shift, the first value now lies at 0x0000000128508000, about 4.6GB with the others lying above 0x0000000311cc8000 or about  12.3GB.

I'm also puzzled that with a total 12GB installed dmesg reports memory being available from zero to 0x000000036c7fffff, i.e. about 13,7GB.

I don't have much confidence in the original onboard memory and if I could be confident of the exact addresses used by each memory module I would be inclined to disable the original 4GB with GRUB's memmap feature.

Comment: A) the onboard memory will most likely be resident below the expandable memory in the address space, and B) physical memory in modern systems isn't generally used linearly any more - see also [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) ... that said, you might be able to [give Linux hints to avoid bad regions of physical memory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76188/221985).

Comment: Your best option is getting someone who is "good with electronics" to desolder the built in RAM and hope that the system works without it.

Comment: @Mokubai: I don't *know*, but I *think* removing the [SPD EEPROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_presence_detect) is sufficient and required.  Should be a lot easier than the DRAM chips.  I'm **assuming** the soldered DRAM is on a different channel than the slot, and I'm assuming normal DDR4 and not LPDDR4.

Answer (score 4):

If your system can still boot far enough on the broken memory that Linux kernel is able to start, you can use `memmap` argument to the kernel to blacklist the area.

To blacklist the whole first 4 GB, you'd set `memmap=1M!4096M`. A tiny bit of low memory is needed for boot.

After blacklisting, stand-alone `memtest86` will still show problems but you can use a usermode tool like `memtester` to check that the memory available to applications is reliable.

Answer (score 2):

When you find a way to change priority you get a worst case scenario. Your OS won't crash, but you will get broken files on copy operations and other bad things happen.

Look at your BIOS settings. Possibly You can disable using DIMM in slot 1.

Comment: Can you explain the reason for the problems you mention?

Comment: The reason for the problems mentioned is that much of the filesystem is cached in RAM. Anything that has been modified will be written back to disk, and with bad RAM the data that gets written back may be corrupted.  And if just the right parts of RAM is bad, it could cause the filesystem driver to completely ruin the filesystem. // Corrupting user data or bricking the filesystem is far worse than just a crash.

Answer (score 1):

In ***theory***, you could desolder the onboard memory and use a SODIMM.  However, it probably isnt worth the effort.  At that point, just buy a cheap, used or older machine.